# Pointer to rvalue object member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, rvalue

This is a very quick question. I have the following code:

```cpp
struct integer {
    int x;
    int& ref() {
        return x;
    }
};

//main...
int* l = &integer{4}.ref();
std::cout << *l;
```

My question is: Isn't `&integer{4}.ref()` a rvalue since it is a temporary object? How can I have a pointer to it? And is it undefined behavior?

Comment: `how can i have a pointer to it??` -- Because the syntax is legal C++?

Comment: The pointer is to `integer{4}.x` and you can just ask for it's adress, since the adress exists. But dereferencing the pointer after that statement is UB, since it is dangling (it points to an object that is no longer there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `integer{4}` is an rvalue, you call `ref()` which returns an `int&` which is always an lvalue.  This allows the code to compile, but you have undefined behavior since you dereference a pointer to an object that no longer exists.

To fix this you can provide a *ref-qualifer* for `ref` which only allows it to be called on lvalues.  That would look like

```
struct integer {
    int x;
    int& ref() & {
        return x;
    }
};
```

and will cause a compiler error if you try to use

```
integer{4}.ref()
```

since `integer{4}` is not an lvalue which `ref` now requires.